# bcache: is sequential_cutoff and other parameters supposed to be permanent?

Tags: linux, bcache

I recall when setting up my system, I changed the `sequential_cutoff` parameter to zero by executing:

```
echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/block/bcache0/bcache/sequential_cutoff
```

Now, after many months I see it back to the default value of `4.0M`. On the other side, the `cache_mode` parameter is still the way I set it, `writeback`. Is the `sequential_cutoff` parameter supposed to be permanently stored on disk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For stuff like writeback, it is stored permanently on disk. However for stuff like sequential_cutoff, readahead, etc. those require you to reset them every boot (you can do this with a script / systemd service).

Comment: Thank you! Is there an exact list of parameters stored on disk?

Comment: I'm not sure, but you might be able to find one. There is a full list of parameters though, but I don't think it tells you about if it is persistent or not. I'm pretty sure everything except caching type and maybe cache eviction algorithm are not stored on disk.